# Não consigo rodar versões anteriores ao R 4.2.1

Tags: r

Olá. Depois de formatar meu computador baixei as versões atualizadas do R 4.2.1 e RStudio e começaram a aparecer erros no script. Baixei a versão que usava antes 3.6.3 mas não abriu o R e no RStudio aparecu a mensagem abaixo:

Error Starting R
The R session failed to start.

RSTUDIO VERSION

```
RStudio 2022.07.1+554, "Spotted Wakerobin" (7872775e, 2022-07-22) for Windows

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36
```

ERROR MESSAGE
[No error available]
´´´´

```
PROCESS OUTPUT
The R session process exited with code 10.
```

```
ERRORS
[No errors emitted]

OUTPUT
[No output emitted]
´´´´



RECENT LOG
C:/Users/Samsung/AppData/Local/RStudio/log/rsession-Samsung.log
2022-09-20T02:47:36.493696Z [rsession-Samsung] ERROR CLIENT EXCEPTION (rsession-Samsung): (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'O' of null;|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/AceEditor.java#4509::setScrollSpeed|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/AceEditorMonitor.java#46::monitor|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/AceEditorMonitor.java#70::execute|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/SchedulerImpl.java#140::execute|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#306::apply|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#345::entry0|||rstudio-0.js#-1::eval|||com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractEditableCell.java#41::viewDataMap|||Client-ID: 33e600bb-c1b1-46bf-b562-ab5cba070b0e|||User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0 Win64 x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36
2022-09-20T02:48:27.404860Z [rsession-Samsung] ERROR system error 3 (O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado) [path: , dcf-file: ]; OCCURRED AT auto __cdecl rstudio::core::FilePath::openForRead::<lambda_1724f433d51cfe6b85c7e603a9e203cb>::operator ()(void) const src/cpp/shared_core/FilePath.cpp:1446; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::projects::`anonymous-namespace'::syncProjectFileChanges(void) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide\open-source-pipeline\spotted-wakerobin\src\cpp\session\projects\SessionProjects.cpp:511
2022-09-20T02:48:27.404860Z [rsession-Samsung] ERROR system error 3 (O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado) [path: , dcf-file: ]; OCCURRED AT auto __cdecl rstudio::core::FilePath::openForRead::<lambda_1724f433d51cfe6b85c7e603a9e203cb>::operator ()(void) const src/cpp/shared_core/FilePath.cpp:1446; LOGGED FROM: void __cdecl rstudio::session::projects::`anonymous-namespace'::syncProjectFileChanges(void) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide\open-source-pipeline\spotted-wakerobin\src\cpp\session\projects\SessionProjects.cpp:511
```

tentei usar a versão 4.2.1 que conseguia abrir e mudar em tools para a versão anterior e ao fazer voltou a mesma mensagem de erro descrita acima e agora não consigo usar o programa.
Alguem pode me ajudar? Obrigada

Comment: Desinstale o R e RStudio. Reinicialize o sistema, e reinstale o R como Administrador e  em seguida o RStudio também como Administrador.

Comment: Eu ja desistalei e instalei três vezes ( versões 4.2.1; 4.0.0 e 3.6.2) e as duas útimas continuam sem funcionar no Rstudio e nem abrem o R console. Precisaria usar a versão 3.2.6 para conseguir rodar os meus dados.

Comment: Mas está instalando os softwares com [**Privilégios de Administrador**](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/topic/executar-um-arquivo-em-lotes-com-privil%C3%A9gios-de-administrador-e1b4b29e-ce46-df49-a9eb-aa292d3d22c5#bkmk_sol1)? Já tentou rodar em [**Modo de Compatibilidade**](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/tornar-aplicativos-ou-programas-mais-antigos-compat%C3%ADveis-com-o-windows-10-783d6dd7-b439-bdb0-0490-54eea0f45938) com versões antigas do OS?

Comment: Sim, como adm. Observei o modo de compatibilidade e mostra compativel com o Windows 8 mas eu usava ele no meu Windows 10. A ultima versão 4.2.1 tbm aparece "compatibilidade windows 8" mas ele abre.

Comment: Tente correr o R no Terminal: `R -q -e "R.version.string"`. Se correr sem erros, tente correr o RGui.exe, que vem com a instalação de qualquer versão do R. Se correr bem, então o problema é de compatibilidade entre o R 3.6.3 e a versão do RStudio que tem instalada.

Comment: Mas a verdadeira solução é corrigir os erros do script. Dá erros porquê, o que é que é incompatível com a nova versão do R?

Comment: Veja este post do [Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel): (em inglês) [Poderíamos simplesmente pegar um post de blog que escrevi em agosto de 2007, ou quase quatorze anos atrás, e executá-lo como está?](https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2021/03/20/).

Comment: depois de desinstalar o R e Rstudio verifique se ficou alguma pasta em "Program Files" desses dois programas. Delete elas e tente instalar novamente. O R primeiro e o Rstudio depois.

Comment: Eu consegui resolver. Como havia instalados antes versões do R, o RStudio não conseguia achar o caminho. Foi só renomear a pasta e funcionou. Obrigada!